# c# npgsql Entity Framework Int Array

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a table column which type is **nullable int[]**. My problem is i cant use this column in my entity object. I tried a lot of things. ext :

```
        public List<int> column1 { get; set; }

        public List?<int> column1 { get; set; }

        public int?[] column1 { get; set; } 

        public int[] column1 { get; set; }
```

Npgsql version : 3.2.5.0 
EF version : 6.0.0.0

Thanks. Atakan.

Comment: I did answer, but found what I believe is a duplicate.  Seems you can't unless you use EF Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closed type system of Entity Framework 6.x doesn't allow for supporting arrays. However, the Npgsql Entity Framework Core does support array columns.

Comment: i got it. probably i will change my db structure.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you have no further questions.